# SQL. Get the user name revenue groping by its first historic weeks

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm quite new to BigQuery and SQL statements and I would like to perform 2 queries. I've already done some queries on my own way, but I can complete this one.

My goal is to achieve in the same sql sentence how much revenue had each group of names on their first 4 weeks (Names should be grouped by their first date).

**INPUT**

```
create table Test(id integer, name varchar(100), time_date date, country varchar(100), car varchar(100), amount integer);
insert into Test(id, name, time_date, country, car, amount) values(1, "usuario1", '2020-09-11', 'UK', 'ford', 100);
insert into Test(id, name, time_date, country, car, amount) values(2, "usuario2", '2020-09-01', 'JP', 'ford', 50);
insert into Test(id, name, time_date, country, car, amount) values(3, "usuario1", '2020-07-11', 'UK', 'kia', 300);
insert into Test(id, name, time_date, country, car, amount) values(4, "usuario3", '2020-09-01', 'JP', 'renault', 400);
insert into Test(id, name, time_date, country, car, amount) values(5, "usuario4", '2020-09-11', 'UK', 'renault', 100);
insert into Test(id, name, time_date, country, car, amount) values(6, "usuario5", '2020-09-11', 'UK', 'kia', 50);
insert into Test(id, name, time_date, country, car, amount) values(7, "usuario85", '2020-09-11', 'UK', 'ford', 200);
insert into Test(id, name, time_date, country, car, amount) values(8, "usuario6", '2020-07-11', 'UK', 'ford', 200);
insert into Test(id, name, time_date, country, car, amount) values(9, "usuario2", '2020-07-11', 'UK', 'ford', 200);
insert into Test(id, name, time_date, country, car, amount) values(9, "usuario2", '2020-07-12', 'UK', 'ford', 50);
```

**QUERY**

- Revenue from each group of user name on their first 3 weeks. Names
  should be grouped by their first date:

This is the question that I can resolve at all, I think that first I should calculate a new variable with the first date for each user. In this case 'usuario2' should have '2020-07-11' in both rows. After, I think that I can calculate the 'next 3 weeks beyond that' and make a sum of the amount. But I really don't know how to do it.

Thanks for your time reading this, any help will be appreciated.

**OUTPUT**

```
User - first_date - Revenue 
usuario1 - 2020-07-11 - 300
usuario2 - 2020-07-11 - 250 => (200 + 50)
usuario3 - 2020-09-01 - 400
usuario4 - 2020-09-11 - 100
usuario5 - 2020-09-11 - 50
usuario6 - 2020-07-11 - 200
usuario85 - 2020-09-11 - 200
```

Revenue:
Each group of name users grouped by first date have his revenue for first 3 weeks. 'Usuario2' is the only one that had another day in that range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmm . . . use a window function to get the earliest time.  Then filter and aggregate:

```
select name, sum(amount)
from (select t.*,
             min(time_date) over (partition by name) as min_time_date
      from Test t
     ) t
where time_date < date_add(min_time_date, interval 4 * 7 day)
group by name;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a35b079d3fd6f9c61322f1a8039d5312) is a db<>fiddle that uses a slightly modified query in Postgres.

Comment: Hello @Gordon Thanks for the answer. Did you test it? Here is my output with your solution?
+----------+-------------+
| name     | sum(amount) |
+----------+-------------+
| usuario1 |         300 |
| usuario2 |         600 |
| usuario2 |         100 |
| usuario3 |         400 |
| usuario4 |         100 |
+----------+-------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
As you can see it miss some records and 'usuario2' amout is wrong.

Comment: @Als . . .The query had a typo in the `group by`, but it should be fine.

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff I've test it and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT name, first_date, SUM(amount) AS Revenue 
FROM (
  SELECT *, MIN(time_date) OVER (PARTITION BY name) AS first_date
  FROM `project.dataset.Test`
) 
WHERE time_date < DATE_ADD(first_date, INTERVAL 3 WEEK)
GROUP BY name, first_date
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - output is

```
Row name        first_date  Revenue  
1   usuario1    2020-07-11  300  
2   usuario2    2020-07-11  250  
3   usuario3    2020-09-01  400  
4   usuario4    2020-09-11  100  
5   usuario5    2020-09-11  50   
6   usuario6    2020-07-11  200  
7   usuario85   2020-09-11  200
```